# How to append html tags before and after a keyword in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider I have a string like this, and I want to append html tags before and after a specific keyword in the string.

```
let name = "George William";

let keyword = "geo";
```

After appending the html tags, i want to get result like this,

```
<strong>Geo</strong>rge William
```

I tried something like this,

```
name.replace(new RegExp(keyword, 'gi'), "<strong>"+keyword+"</strong>");
```

But it results like this,

```
<strong>geo</strong>rge William
```

How can i get the result with exact "case" in the original name?

Comment: Do a name.match first and save the result as a variable, then insert that variable instead of keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the matched substring in your result using `$&`

```js
let name = 'George William';
let keyword = 'geo';

console.log(name.replace(new RegExp(keyword, 'gi'), '<strong>$&</strong>'));
```

Comment: Thanks for this one liner, works as expected. this code works even there are multiple keyword occurrences  in the name. Great.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the prettiest code I have ever written, but it doesn't use Regular Expressions and it does work for ignoring the case, while making this a re-usable function that doesn't have to be tied to the `<strong>` tag specifically.

```js
let name = "George William";

let keyword = "geo";

const newHtml = (str, key, tagName) => {
  return str.toLowerCase()
    .split(key.toLowerCase())
    .map((val) => {
      if (val !== '') {
        return val;
      }
      else {
        let idx = str.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase());
        return `<${tagName}>${str.split('').slice(idx, key.length).join('')}</${tagName}>`;
      }
    })
    .join('');
};
  
console.log(newHtml(name, keyword, 'strong'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @temporalside answer was simpler than this.

Comment: @RubanrajRavichandran => It absolutely is and is 100% the better answer. I am just not that good with Regular Expressions, so I tried to give an answer that someone else could use that is trying to avoid them. :)